# Solving the equation $2x^3+3x^2+x-6n^2 = 0$

Tags: diophantine-equations

It came up when I was trying to solve the equality $\sum_{i = 1}^{x}i^2 =n^2$ for integers $x$ and $i$. I've reduced it to the equation $2x^3+3x^2+x-6n^2 = 0$, which I don't know how to tackle. Is there some sort of method for solving a diophantine equation like this?

Comment: you should learn elliptic curve and you can solve this question in minutes.

Comment: @Back2Basic, could you show me how, and maybe give me a good resource to start with?

Comment: There is just the one solution. Pretty famous episode, related to the Leech lattice, or rather, one way of working on it. Apparently page 258 in Mordell's book.

Comment: Yeah, Mordell says it is difficult, G. N. Watson gave a complicated answer in 1919, Ljunggren in 1952 by a Pell equation in a quadratic field. Mordell calls it the problem of Lucas on the square pyramid. Why are you considering this? Oh, just one nontrivial solution: the others are $x=0,1,-1.$

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Could you post the links to these solutions you're finding? Maybe I can understand one of them.

Comment: Mordell, *Diophantine Equations* (1969), Wolfgang Ebeling, *Lattices and Codes*, 2nd edition (2002).

Comment: Thanks. I know the solution thanks to the magic of wolfram, I just wanted to know how to get there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alrighty; some elementary solutions were found in the 1980's. Henri Cohen summarizes these on pages  424 to 427  of
*Number Theory: Volume I: Tools and Diophantine Equations,*
  see

https://books.google.com/books?id=qxCWoFO-oxYC&pg=PA424&lpg=PA424&dq=lucas+square+pyramid&source=bl&ots=2DN6KgNBgA&sig=Gq__ESOX33BwpACDEWB6zEXLJ60&hl=en&sa=X&ei=S1nEVNmLN8SyoQS054GgCQ&ved=0CEEQ6AEwCjgK#v=onepage&q=lucas%20square%20pyramid&f=false

Comment: Can the sum of two co-prime fifth powers ever be a perfect square ?

Comment: @Lucian, no, found it, see http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa86/aa8631.pdf